# How do you say "I'm gonna get you!"?

Tags: traducción, español-neutral

When I'm chasing my baby around the room, I frequently tell him, "I'm gonna get you!" and catch him and tickle him.  Is there a similar expression in Spanish?  I'd love to find something that can be used everywhere, but regional answers are appreciated as well.  It should express that we're playing, not that I'm going to get him because he's in trouble or anything.

Comment: I wonder if "agarrar" can be used for this sense? I think it usually means "to grab".

Comment: This is so region dependant

Comment: @César: Looking for the most neutral ways to communicate the most region dependant expressions is a great use of a site intended for experts I think!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Argentina you would say

> '¡Te voy a atrapar!' (prefered)
>
> '¡Te voy a agarrar!'

I think 'Te voy a agarrar' makes it sound like he is in trouble, but not so much, you could still use it.

Comment: +1 for including `te voy a agarrar`. Personally though, it doesn't make it sound like the person's in trouble much. As a speaker of Mexican Spanish, it would be my prefered expression. :)

Comment: I guess it depends on how you say it, if 'Te voy a agarrar!' in said in a playful way then it's ok.

Comment: I chose this answer because it referenced the location it was used, and it seems like it will be the most useful for my area.

Answer (score 10):

I would use some variant with `pillar`:

> ¡Que te pillo!
>
> ¡Te voy a pillar!

But I don't know about the neutrality of the verb "pillar" in other countries (I'm from Spain).

**Update:**

I would certainly use `coger` too, but I know it is not "neutral" in many parts of America.

Comment: "pillar" is not used at least in Mexico.

Comment: "pillar" is very used in Chile.

Comment: Esta uso yo. También se oye con frecuencia _A que te pillo_.

Comment: "pillar" is not used in Venezuela either. I heard spaniards using it a lot

Answer (score 5):

Some neutral expessions are:

> ¡Te atraparé!
>
> ¡Te voy a atrapar!
>
> ¡No te me escaparás!

Comment: Neutral, meaning what? I'd never say, and I never hear, "¡te atraparé!" in Spain. I think it's good if we add a note about where our answers apply (as far as we know) for the sake of reference, as @MikMik has done on this same page.

Comment: @CesarGon "atrapar" is pretty neutral. "El gato atrapó al ratón". Look at http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=atrapar . On the other hand, "pillar" is not used in Mexico for anything.

Comment: I don't dispute that. But, as an idiom, I'd never use that, and I never hear that, in the context described by the OP. I understand and am able to use the verb "atrapar", but it sounds terribly poetic for everyday speech, and I bet this is extensive to the average Spaniard. Hence my complain about your claim for neutrality and the lack of a regional qualifier.

Comment: I agree it sounds more neutral (I guess everywhere but in Spain)